# Atualizar as informações na pagina ao fazer uma alteração no BD

Tags: php, sql-update

Digamos que eu tenha `button value="+1"` na minha pagina, e toda vez que eu clico nesse botão é feito um update no banco de dados, a pagina faz o refresh e exibi uma mensagem de sucesso ou de erro. Esse processo de update é simples! Só que ao retornar do refresh as informações não vem atualizadas.

Exemplo

O campo *níveis* na tabela *X* atualmente tem o valor de 10. Uso uma query e exibo essa informação! Nessa mesma pagina adiciono o `button` com o codigo do `UPDATE`, e cada vez que clico no `button` aumenta um nivel no BD, só que ao clicar nesse `button` a pagina vai da o refresh e vai exibir a mensagem. Porém mesmo que tudo tenha ocorrido de forma ideal, o retorno das informações será antiga, ou seja, ainda exibirá *NIVEL = 10*, sendo que já foi alterado no BD, ou seja o *nivel* já é igual a 11.

Como fazer então para que o retorno dessas informações já seja as "atuais"?

```
<?php  
    include_once("head.php"); 
    $ID = 1;
    $niveis = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM x WHERE ID = ?");
    $niveis->bindValue(1, $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $niveis->execute();    
    $niveis_dados = $niveis->fetchObject();
?>

    NIVEL ATUAL: <?php echo $niveis_dados->NIVEL ?>
    <div class="DA">Aumentar/Diminuir :         </div>
    <div class="DB">
                    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <button value="1" name="UPDOWN" type="submit">+</button>
                        <button value="-1" name="UPDOWN" type="submit">-</button>
                    </form>
    </div>
</div> 


<?php
    //CODIGO DE UPDATE DO NIVEL
    if(isset($_POST['UPDOWN']))
        {

        //AUMENTAR ou DIMINUIR
            $UPDOW = $_POST['UPDOWN'];

        //NOVO NIVEL    
            $novo_nivel = $niveis_dados->NIVEL + $UPDOW;
            echo "Novo nivel: ".$novo_nivel;

        //UPDATE 1 ::: NOVO NIVEL
            $up_props = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE x SET NIVEL = :1 WHERE ID = :2");
            $up_props->bindParam(":1", $novo_nivel , PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $up_props->bindParam(":2", $ID , PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $up_props_executa = $up_props->execute();       
        }
?>
```

Comment: Coloca o código fonte, para garantir vc precisa fazer um novo select para pegar a informação atualizada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para pegar as informações já atualizadas é ncessário fazer um select após o update, como você ja tem ele pronto basta transforma numa função que pede dois paramêtros, a conexão e o id, caso o id não seja informado o valor padrão será 1.

```
function buscarNivel($pdo, $id=1){
    $niveis = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM x WHERE ID = ?");
    $niveis->bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    if($niveis->execute() === false){
        return false;
    }
    return $niveis->fetchObject();
}
```

A função deve ser chamada duas vezes uma no ínicio e outra após o update.

```
//código omitido
$up_props_executa = $up_props->execute(); 
$novo = buscarNivel($pdo, $id);
```

Comment: me desculpa!! Mas se pode me mostrar um exemplo já funcionando? Porque to tentando aqui e não to conseguindo!

Comment: @ivanveloso, oq vc não está conseguindo?

Comment: Ainda não to conseguindo trazer as informações já atualizadas! Usei a função no inicio e logo depois do update! Só que não ta adiantando!!

Answer (score 0):

Você deve executar a query SELECT, a que puxa as informações do banco, após a query de UPDATE, que soma o +1 no caso.

Comment: pode explicar um pouco melhor? Porque acrescentei aqui o código do prepare só que ainda não veio atualizada!

Comment: Pegue todo o segundo código PHP que tens, e jogue antes do primeiro.